# Virtual Android device error?

Tags: eclipse, windows-8

I have installed the android bundle sdk from android.com and I have created a virtual device. When I want to start my application with the virtual device it hangs at the android logo forever. In the console it gives me "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the hardware virtualization on? If not, turn on in the BIOS.

Comment: My cpu has vt but not my bios. Can I use something else?

Comment: you can use x86 emulator. Try it [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-gingerbread-emulator)

Comment: I'm on Windows. Does this bypass my BIOS? My cpu supports vt but not my bios?